# Error when using vector: what(): vector::_M_range_check

Tags: c++, c++14

I'm a beginner programmer and I'm trying to write a program that asks the user the following:

- P - Print Numbers
- A - Add Numbers
- M - Display The Mean Of The Numbers
- S - Display The Smallest Number
- L - Display The Largest Number
- Q - Quit

The user has to type these letters (whether lower case or upper case) in order to work with it.The aim is to create a list of numbers only using vector and do the above actions

For example if I type p it should display the list is empty(if there is no number in the list) or display the numbers in this format:[ 1 2 3 ]

Apply the same format here for other choices

So this is the code that I've written myself:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int Count {1};
    char selection {};
    int Numbers {};
    double Sum {0};
    double Average {};
    int Minimum {};
    int Maximum {};
    vector <int> list;
    do {
        cout << "P - Print Numbers" << endl;
        cout << "A - Add Numbers" << endl;
        cout << "M - Display The Mean Of The Numbers" << endl;
        cout << "S - Display The Smallest Number" << endl;
        cout << "L - Display The Largest Number" << endl;
        cout << "Q - Quit" << endl;
        cout << "\nEnter Your Choice: ";
        cin >> selection;
        switch(selection){
            case 'P':
            case 'p':
                if(list.size() == 0){
                    cout << "\n[] - The List Is Empty" << endl;
                } else{
                    cout << "\n[ ";
                    for(size_t i{0}; i<=list.size(); ++i)
                        cout << list.at(i) << " ";
                    cout << "]" << endl;
                }
                break;
            case 'a':
            case 'A':
                cout << "\nEnter Your Number: ";
                cin >> Numbers;
                if (Count == 1){
                    Maximum = Numbers;
                    Minimum = Numbers;
                }
                if (Numbers > Maximum)
                    Maximum = Numbers;
                if (Numbers < Minimum)
                    Minimum = Numbers;
                list.push_back(Numbers);
                cout << "Added " << Numbers << endl;
                Count += 1;
                break;
            case 'm':
            case 'M':
                if (list.size() == 0)
                    cout << "Unable To Calculate The Mean - No Data" << endl;
                else {
                for (size_t j{0}; j<=list.size(); ++j){
                    Sum += list.at(j);
                    Average = Sum / list.size();
                }
                cout << "\nThe Mean Is : " << Average << endl;
                }
                break;
            case 's':
            case 'S':
                if (list.size() == 0)
                    cout << "Unable To Determine The Smallest Number - List Is Empty" << endl;
                else
                    cout << "\nThe smallest number is : " << Minimum << endl;
                break;
            case 'l':
            case 'L':
                 if (list.size() == 0)
                    cout << "Unable To Determine The Largest Number - List Is Empty" << endl;
                else
                    cout << "\nThe Largest number is : " << Maximum << endl;
                break;
            case 'q':
            case 'Q':
                cout << "Goodbye!!" << endl;
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Unknown Selection, Please Try Again!" << endl;
        }
    } while (selection != 'q' && selection != 'Q');
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is I can successfully add the number but when I try to print the list I get this:

```
    terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 1) >= this->size() (which is 1)
```

Now ofcourse as I said I can run this without any errors or warnings.I also tried to change `size_t` to `int` but I got two warnings...and I'm also using `.push_back()` for the vector so I don't have an empty vector...

Any help would be great..Thank you :)

Comment: The less-than-or-equal comparison in `for (size_t j{0}; j<=list.size(); ++j)` is not correct.  Consider the last iteration... what will the index be, and will it be valid?

Comment: Thank you guys...Finally after 3 hours :)))) ...All I had to do was just to remove the equal out of it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The less-than-or-equal comparison in `for (size_t j{0}; j<=list.size(); ++j)` is not correct.

Consider the last iteration... `j` will be equal to `list.size()`.

Instead, the canonical iteration over list elements is:

```cpp
    for (size_t i{0}; i < list.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << list[i] << " ";
```

As shown above, you could change `list.at(i)` to `list[i]`, since you know the index will be valid.

Finally, I would suggest not using the name `list` for your vector, since that is the name of a linked-list type in the C++ standard library.

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty self-evident: you are accessing an element by an index that is out of the range of [0; size()).

```
for (size_t j{0}; j<=list.size(); ++j){
   ...
}
```

And other places where you iterate like this.

Change to `j<list.size()`, since array indexes are 0-based and go up to but not including `size()`.

Next time you encounter such an issue you can use debugger to see where exactly the exception is thrown and why.

Comment: Thank you :))...that just fixed it